# PHP script doesen't insert data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I've created this script to insert some data from PHP to MySQL, but it doesen't work, and I don't know why.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
  $session_created=1;
  $session_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession'];
  $session_query_result = $DBcon->query($session_query);
  $user_row=$session_query_result->fetch_array();
}
  if(isset($_POST['create_post_button'])){
    $post_name = $DBcon->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['post_title']));
    $post_content = $DBcon->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['post_content']));
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
    $post_date=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    $post_categ_id = $DBcon->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['post_category']));
    $post_creator = $user_row['user_name'];
    $pass_flag=0;
    $error_msg_cp = "Posted!";
      $create_post_query = "INSERT INTO posts(post_name,post_content,post_date,
        post_categ_id,post_user_name) VALUES ('$post_name','$post_content','$post_date','
        $post_categ_id','$post_creator')";
        echo "<br><br><br><br>".$create_post_query;
        if($DBcon->query($create_post_query)){
          $error_msg_cp="Error, pug!";
        }
        echo $error_msg_cp;
  }
```

Thank you!
Edit:
The result of this code is:
[image]
Even with `ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout');` it doesen't display the error...

This is the structure of the posts table in MySQL:
[image]

Comment: no error message ? can't say and won't guess. Unless by reading in cards or crystal ball. first set errors to display on screen with `ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout');`

Comment: I tried this. It doesen't display anything...

Comment: what is the value of `$_POST['create_post_button']`. Plus you need to nest that second If statement into the first or check `$user_row` exists

Comment: what does the `echo` statement in your code display ?

Comment: I will edit with the result. Wait a little.

Comment: Also, please use prepared statements.

Comment: What is the format of your column `post_date`?

Comment: I've edited my post with the posts table structure.

Comment: give us here the `$create_post_query`

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Pierre Displayed in the top of image.

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot is so small I didn't catch the request. It seems there's a space or newline before the `1` (post_categ_id), as @Syscall said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have a newline in your integer field.

Change your query like this. Single quote around `'$post_categ_id'` has changed.

```
$create_post_query = "INSERT INTO posts(post_name,post_content,post_date,
  post_categ_id,post_user_name)
  VALUES ('$post_name','$post_content','$post_date',
          '$post_categ_id','$post_creator')";
  echo "<br><br><br><br>".$create_post_query;
  if (!$DBcon->query($create_post_query)){
      $error_msg_cp="Error, pug!";
  }
```

**NB** I suggest you to read this post [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent your queries against SQL injections.

Answer (score -2):

Change your insert query as follows, use `'{$variable}'` instead of `'$variabe'`

```
$create_post_query = "INSERT INTO posts(post_name,post_content,post_date,
        post_categ_id,post_user_name) VALUES ('{$post_name}','{$post_content}','{$post_date}','
        {$post_categ_id}','{$post_creator}')";
```

Comment: don't think that will make the difference, php engine is smart enough to capture `$xxxx` until it encounters characters who can't be part of an identifier (and that's the case for `'`). I never user brackets in such case

Comment: We can try for a better solution if you can provide your mysql error message.

Comment: There isn't a mysql error message. I've tried this INSERT in PhpMyAdmin and it worked. So i think that the problem comes from the php code.

Comment: Try to change your date to $post_date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');